# Python Data Frame Groupby

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: Group by code goes here]
My code

```
    datafile = "LoL_raw_data.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(datafile)
    group = df.groupby(['Team', Opponent',"Result"],as_index=False).sum()
```

I am taking a league of legends database from a previous worlds and want to get the average gold per position on the team. League of legends is a MOBA with 5 players per team. Currently, I am attempting to get the amount of gold each player makes per game in a percentage compared to the total gold the team earned.  The total gold is the gold collected by each of the 5 players on respective teams.
Now in the above screen shot on line 3, team BYG vs UOL faced against each other twice. BYG won both of those times and the groupby combined this data, which is an unwanted result.  My question, is it possible to split this information somehow?

[image: Database head]

See above for head of database.

Hope this question makes sense.

NOTE:  I found another method of doing this.  Essentially I created a new data frame and gave each team member a game number unique to there team and game.  I was able to split those games up via this way to collect all information needed.  However, if anyone knows of a simpler or more eloquent way, feel free to drop that.  I would be curious to see your ideas.

Comment: Please take the time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to add code to a question.

Comment: This needs a bit more detail on *how* you intend to group the data. I suppose, only a minority of us are sports experts and have the necessary background knowledge. (oh, and by the way, some advice for a newcomer: this community doesn't use complementary closings or salutations - just the bare question plus details; you're welcome)

Comment: And please, please, include some input data as copyable text so that we can reproduce...